# Loading additional data for authenticated user with CakePHP Auth Component

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have some additional data I want to load on each request for the authenticated user. I recently adopted the Auth Component. Previously, I was loading this additional data in my AppController's `beforeFilter`. I suppose I could leave it there and wrap the code within a test against `$this->Auth->user();`, but wanted to see if there were better way for both these items.

So the question is two part:

- Is there a built in method of the Auth Component where I can load in additional data on each request for the authenticated user.
- If not, is there a better way to do so than checking `$this->Auth->user();` in the AppController's `beforeFilter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- no
- few options

  - overloading auth component
  - roll your own
  - do the auth check, if they are logged in and the extra data is not around get it. it will obviously be an extra query, but its once per login... hardly a server killer.

Comment: I am already extending the Auth Component for some LDAP checks. Where would you suggest putting it in that case?

Comment: Thanks for the lone response. I didn't find much to hook into on the Auth Component, so for now I will just do the inline `$this->Auth->user();` checks until something better presents itself.